# Infinispan 5.3.0 hotrod client issue with remote cache

Tags: mysql, caching, infinispan

I have a simple infinispan cache configuration as follows

Application Server (server 1) --> standalone infinispan cache (server 2) ---> msql DB (server 3)

Where I have created a standalone "local cache" on server 2 using "standalone.xml" and configured mysql table in same file.

My application server is using the hot rod client to communicate with the remote cache on server 2. However while using the client i can put(key1, value) into the cache but I can never retrieve the value associated with the key. If I do a get on key1 null is returned and the cache size is returned as -1. KeySey() returns all the keys however.

Removing the mysql connector config from standalone.xml solves the problem but I need to persist the cache items.

If i use the memcached protocol using spymemcached client instead I do not see this and cache items are written to database. Any ideas ?

Also are there any examples out there of using spymemcached client with infinispan ?

Thanks,
Sven

Comment: Hmmm, strange. What type are `key1` and `value`? Maybe enable TRACE log on org.infinispan package to see what is going on. In particular, grep for `PutKeyValueCommand` and `GetKeyCommand`